# Authentication failed on the server. Google maps api. Android

Tags: android

I have this message when my application starting.

```
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: AIzaSyBRaM8yt1*****MJRlbNI4WpvtSdl0Oc
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): CB:A8:D1:DB:D7:8B:D0:36:68:A8:23:***:9A:83:35:1C:2E;com.neustart.****
```

Exactly in my android SDK installed Google Play services, and everything is ok with my code, becouse this applicaton correclty started and worked when i buid it on another my pc. I tried to make full copie of my android studio from pc when build was correct, but problem still exist.

[image]

What could be the problem ?

Comment: different systems are having different sha1 .. if you want to run your code in other pc you have to generate sha1 for that system and again u need to get api key in console for that system sha1 ..

Comment: @priyankamorisetti thank u, your comment help me to solve my problem :)
u can type it as separate answer and i will make it "Best answer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

different systems are having different sha1 .. if you want to run your code in other pc you have to generate sha1 for that system and again u need to get api key in console for that system sha1 ...